# RxJs Observable How to Handle Success

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is there a way to handle the success of an RxJs POST or GET (or all CRUD operations for that matter) in the Angular service, instead of in the Angular component (via subscribe)?

I would like to set up a BehaviorSubject to emit that a user has successfully logged in. I was thinking of sharing the success results with various sibling components via my BehaviorSubject (`this.loggedIn.next(true)`), as these sibling components need to make changes based on a single service `userLogin()` call.

**This is my userLogin method and BehaviorSubject in my AuthenticationService:**

```
private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

userLogin(user): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .post(this.apiUrl, user, httpOptions)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

**This is pseudo code for what I want in my AuthenticationService:**

```
private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

userLogin(user): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .post(this.apiUrl, user, httpOptions),
  this.loggedIn.next(true),            <<--------
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just move the `subscribe` inside the service ? I don't see the point of your question, of course you can do that ...

Comment: I am also subscribing in my component service calls. Will that be OK?

Comment: Well no, you asked to not do that ...

Comment: Hence why I am asking whether there is a way to handle a success the same way I would handle `catchError`?

Comment: Yes, move the subscribe into the service, and use `.next` to send data to your behavior subject !

Comment: Thanks for the advice. No need to answer in such a way. If I knew the answer I would not post a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

userLogin(user): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .post(this.apiUrl, user, httpOptions)
  .pipe(map((res: any) => {
                this.loggedIn.next(true)
                return res;
        }), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the component has the `subscribe` removed

Comment: @Maryannah Thanks for the advice. I will make sure to use subscribe in all my components

Comment: @onmyway or you can put it in the service to avoid duplicates (just be sure to not return anything and remove the subscribes from your components)

Answer (score 0):

handle it after subscribed

```
    ngOnInit() {
            this.loading.present();
            this.yourService.getUsers().
                subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(this.data);
                },
               //Errr----->***      
              err =>{ console.log('HTTP Error', err),this.loading.dismiss()}
            );
        }
```

in service it can be handle

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/error-handling-with-angular-6-tips-and-best-practices192

```
 handleError(error) {
    ///your error
       let errorMes = '';
       if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
         // client-side error
         errorMes = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
       } else {
         // server-side error
         errorMes = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: 
         ${error.message}`;
       }
       window.alert(errorMes);
       return throwError(errorMes);
     }
```

Comment: Tx for the response, but I would like to handle it in the service and not the component

Comment: wait i will change it

Comment: Hey ORBIT. Thanks for the help. I am trying to handle SUCCESS in my service. ;)